# Having trouble getting started on go. `package main` throws run time error- index out of range?

Tags: go, jupyter-notebook, program-entry-point

I'm a complete beginner in go. And I just installed gophernotes and intend to use Jupyter Notebook for main programming.

This program gives the following error when run in Jupyter:

```
Cell1: package main
Out1: runtime error: index out of range
Cell2: import "fmt"
      func main() {
          fmt.Println("hello world")
      }
      main()
Out2: hello world
```

When I write the same in a `test.go` and execute from bash: `go run test.go`, I get the following:

```
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:JUPYTER deepak$ go run test.go 
go: disabling cache (/Users/deepak/Library/Caches/go-build) due to initialization failure: open /Users/deepak/Library/Caches/go-build/log.txt: permission denied
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:6:1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that having "package main" is a problem. The way Go works with Jupyter is apparently different than how Go works on its own. You don't need a package statement with Jupyter.

Also you should never call `main()`. That is done automatically when you run the program with `go run` or `go build`.

I am not familiar with Jupyter Notebook and how it uses Go. Maybe you do need to call the function. If that is the case do not name your function `main` because that is simply confusing.

From what I have seen of Jupyter / Go examples you don't need a Go function you can just list out the code.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea on `go: disabling cache (/Users/deepak/Library/Caches/go-build) due to initialization failure: open /Users/deepak/Library/Caches/go-build/log.txt: permission denied


# command-line-arguments`?

Comment: @DeepakMP I would check your file permissions. And make sure that directory exists. The error message is pretty straight forward: something is denying permission to open that named file.